# How to parse xml file by JDOM to find the main attribute's content

Tags: java, xml, bpmn, jdom

I want to parse my xml file (BPMN 2.0) to read the content of `<text>` tag by JDOM. I mean to read "Test of myAnnotation"

```
  <textAnnotation id="myAnnotation_ID" signavio:alignment="left" textFormat="text/plain">
     <text>Test of myAnnotation</text>
  </textAnnotation>
```

Here is my code:

```
Document doc = new SAXBuilder().build(myfile);
BPMN2NS = Namespace.getNamespace("http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL");
Element procElem = doc.getRootElement().getChild("process", BPMN2NS);
List<Element> textAnnotation = procElem.getChildren("textAnnotation", BPMN2NS);
```

But what I already can read is `[Element: <text [Namespace: http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL]/>],` as the "content" of "textAnnotation" element.

Any idea how can I read "Test of myAnnotation" ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that once you get your textAnnotation Element, you just have to get all children named "text" and get the text inside by using the following code.

```
    Document doc = new SAXBuilder().build(myfile);

    Namespace BPMN2NS = Namespace.getNamespace("http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL");
    Element procElem = doc.getRootElement().getChild("process", BPMN2NS);
    List<Element> textAnnotations = procElem.getChildren("textAnnotation", BPMN2NS);
    List<Element> texts = textAnnotations.get(0).getChildren("text", BPMN2NS);
    System.out.print(texts.get(0).getText());
```

Comment: It again prints "[Element: <text [Namespace: omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL]/>]";

Comment: "texts.get(0)" returns a jdom.Element which is your result.
getText() method available on jdom.Element  returns a String...

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXml can do it:

```
final String data = "<textAnnotation id=\"myAnnotation_ID\" signavio:alignment=\"left\" textFormat=\"text/plain\">\n" +
            "     <text>Test of myAnnotation</text>\n" +
            "  </textAnnotation>";
final SimpleXml simple = new SimpleXml();
final Element element = simple.fromXml(data);
System.out.println(element.children.get(0).text);
```

Will output:

```
Test of myAnnotation
```

From maven central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.codemonstur</groupId>
    <artifactId>simplexml</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```